# How do I only get a picture from PRAW

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, praw

I am trying to use PRAW for a discord.py command. However I do not want videos to play when I execute the command, so is there a way I can only get pictures when I get the post?

Here is what I have:

```
@commands.command()
    async def aww(self, ctx):
      subreddit = reddit.subreddit("aww")

      allsubs = []

      top = subreddit.top(limit = 50)

      for submission in top: 
        allsubs.append(submission)
      
      randomsub = random.choice(allsubs)

      name = randomsub.title 
      url = randomsub.url 
      
      em = discord.Embed(
        title = name, 
        color = discord.Color.blurple()
      )
      em.set_image(url = url)

      await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the PRAW api only provides you a url (str) without any information on the URL, I'd suggest adding some conditionals to ensure that the url is a photo and not a video.

e.g.

```
randomsub = random.choice(allsubs)
extension = randomsub.url[len(randomsub.url) - 3 :].lower()
while "jpg" not in extension or "png" not in extension:
    randomsub = random.choice(allsubs)
    extension = randomsub.url[len(randomsub.url) - 3 :].lower()
```

And proceed from there. Obviously there are more graceful ways of solving this but the underlying point is the same.